# How do I set the containing DIV to have a max width, but allow to be narrower if content doesn't max it out, and float left?

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to build a screen that shows a list of products, DIV tile after DIV tile, say 6 across.  That wants to be in the left DIV *up to* 85% wide.

Then on the right DIV 15% wide, I want a Buy Now button and other information.  This is so they can buy a 'Bundle' of products.

Initially I thought I would use a DIV called bundle-tile.  Then I would have a DIV called bundle-tile-buy which would contain the buy button and other bits.

bundle-tile would be using this CSS:

```
.product-bundletile
{
position: relative;
width: 14%;
width: calc(100% / 7);
float: left;
padding-bottom: 5px;
margin-right: 28px;
}
```

While the bundle-tile-buy would be basically the same, without the right margin.

Problem there is, if you have more than 7 items in the bundle, the Buy Now button would be on the end of row two.  Not the best option.

So I thought it would be nicer if you had a left div container and a right div container.

The left one would be 85% float left, and the right one would be 15% float left.

But... here's the issue.  I don't want to have the right one over on the right side, if the left one isn't maxxed out.  The purpose is to always have the Buy Button DIV at the upper right corner of the area, while the DIV containing the products is on the left.

If there are tons of products, it would show loads on the left and the buy at the top right.  If there are just 3 products, then the buy button would be tagged on the end of the third product.

But I don't see how to make the 85% wide DIV, *up to* 85% wide.  Not even with max-width.

Comment: This is a lot of text, could you provide a working example (fiddle) demonstrating your issue?

Comment: It's a little difficult to visualise your question, would you be able to create a demo using jsfiddle or codepen? Thanks